# Java input read String for validation

Tags: java, validation, input

How to validate input beetween 2 String described as Y and N using scanner ?

```
System.out.println("Are you sure?");
String StrInput = scan.nextLine();

if(strInput = Y && StrInput = N){
    System.out.println("Nice choice");
}else{
    System.out.println("Please Input only with Y or N");
}
```

Comment: i know it didnt work, but i want to know how the right logic for that, i have no clue, please help, thank you!

Comment: Use `equals()` method of String class to check equality of two string like `strInput.equals("Y")`

Comment: Thank you!  it works

Answer (score 1):

As said by Rono as well Use Equals and use || condition between input checking, it can be either Y or N. Below snippet would help

```
    System.out.println("Are you sure?");
    String strInput = scan.nextLine();

    if(strInput.equals("Y") || strInput.equals("N")){
        System.out.println("Nice choice");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Please Input only with Y or N");
    }
```